# How to disable dragging of JToolbar?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, border-layout, jtoolbar

How to disable dragging of JToolbar? I placed it in a BorderLayout. I tried finding a method. Is there such a method ? THanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
toolBar.setFloatable( false);
```